# Beginner natural deduction, proof verification

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I would like to prove the following proofs using the system of natural deduction and I am having a little difficulty:

1) $\exists x \space \text{slimy}(x)$, $\forall x \space (\text{slimy}(x) \rightarrow (\text{big}(x) \vee \text{toad}(x)))$, $\forall x \space (\text{big}(x) \rightarrow \text{mighty}(x)) \space \vdash \exists x \space \text{mighty}(x)$

My attempt:

```
 1: ∃x slimy(x)                                               premise
 2: ∀x (slimy(x) → (big(x) ∨ toad(x)))                        premise
 3: ∀x (big(x) → mighty(x))                                   premise
   ----------------------------------------------------------
 4: slimy(c)                                                  assumption
 5: slimy(c) → (big(c) ∨ toad(c))                             ∀-elim 2
 6: big(c) ∨ toad(c)                                          →-elim 5,4
 7: big(c)                                                    ∨-elim 6
 8: big(c) → mighty(c)                                        ∀-elim 3
 9: mighty(c)                                                 →-elim 8,7
10: ∃x mighty(x)                                              ∃-intro 9
   ----------------------------------------------------------
11: ∃x mighty(x)                                              ∃-elim 1,4–10
```

2) $\exists x \space \text{slimy}(x) \wedge \exists x \space \text{toad}(x)$, $\forall x \space(\text{slimy}(x) \wedge \text{toad}(x) \rightarrow \text{mighty}(x))$, $\forall x \space (\text{mighty}(x) \rightarrow \text{big}(x)) \space \vdash \space \exists x \space \text{big}(x)$

My attempt:

```
 1: ∃x slimy(x) ∧ ∃x toad(x)                                  premise
 2: ∀x (slimy(x) ∧ toad(x) → mighty(x))                       premise
 3: ∀x (mighty(x) → big(x))                                   premise
 4: slimy(c) ∧ toad(c)                                        assumption
   ----------------------------------------------------------
 5: slimy(c) ∧ toad(c) → mighty(c)                            ∀-elim 2
 6: mighty(c)                                                 →-elim 5,4
 7: mighty(c) → big(c)                                        ∀-elim 3
 8: big(c)                                                    →-elim 7,6
 9: ∃x big(x)                                                 ∃-intro 8
   ----------------------------------------------------------
10: ∃x big(x)                                                 ∃-elim 1,4-9
```

**Could someone please explain which lines are incorrect, and why they are incorrect?**

Comment: Part of the problem may be that the existence of a slimy $x$ in part (1) does not imply the existence of a mighty $x$, because $x$ could be a toad.  Your line 7 tries to deduce $A$ from $A \vee B$, which is not valid.

Comment: In part (2), $\exists x \,\text{slimy}(x)$ and $\exists x \,\text{toad}(x)$ is not the same as $\exists x (\text{slimy}(x) \wedge \text{toad}(x))$.  Said otherwise, there exists a slimy being and there exists a toad, but there is no guarantee that there exists a slimy toad.  Hence the assumption of Line 4 is not justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
 1: ∃x slimy(x)                                               premise
 2: ∀x (slimy(x) → (big(x) ∨ toad(x)))                        premise
 3: ∀x (big(x) → mighty(x))                                   premise
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 4: slimy(c)                                                  assumption
```

This is not an assumption.  This is existential elimination from Premise 1.

```
4': slimy(c)                                                  ∃-elim 1
 5: slimy(c) → (big(c) ∨ toad(c))                             ∀-elim 2
 6: big(c) ∨ toad(c)                                          →-elim 5,4
 7: big(c)                                                    ∨-elim 6
```

That is not how disjunction elimination works.   If you know $\sf P\vee R$, you are assured that *at least one* of $\sf P$ or $\sf R$ is true, but you cannot be certain that either in particular *will* be true.

Only if the conclusion $\sf Q$ is an consequence of $\sf P$ *and* also a consequence of $\sf R$ can the disjunction be eliminated to imply the conclusion.

The rule of disjunction elimination is: $\sf P\vee R, P\to Q, R\to Q\vdash Q$

You won't be able to use this rule.  Rather you have to prepare for a constructive dilemma.

```
7': toad(c) → toad(x)                                         tautology 
 8: big(c) → mighty(c)                                        ∀-elim 3
 9: mighty(c)                                                 →-elim 8,7
```

As stated we can't use the old statement 7, rather we use the rule of constructive dilemma $\sf P\vee R, P\to Q, R\to S\vdash Q\vee S$

```
9': mighty(c) ∨ toad(c)                                       ∨-dilemma 6,7',8
10: ∃x mighty(x)                                              ∃-intro 9
```

Using the new 9 you can only conclude

```
10: ∃x (mighty(x) ∨ toad(x))                                  ∃-intro 9', 4
```

That is as strong as the three premises infer.

---

2)

```
1: ∃x slimy(x) ∧ ∃x toad(x)                                  premise
2: ∀x ((slimy(x) ∧ toad(x)) → mighty(x))                     premise
3: ∀x (mighty(x) → big(x))                                   premise
4: slimy(c) ∧ toad(c)                                        assumption
```

You can't make an assumption unless you intend to discharge it; all assumptions must be discharged.   Further, you cannot reach this line from existential elimination either, because premise 1 asserts that there are things which are slimy and things which are toads, but does not guarantee the existence of any thing that is *both* slimy and toad.

You can't go any further.  All this line of reasoning will conclude is that :

```
∀x ((slimy(x) ∧ toad(x)) → big(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you would be 'having a little difficulty' since both arguments are invalid, so can *not* be proven!

For 1, a counterexample is: You have a small, slimy, and un-mighty toad, and nothing else. That would make all premises true, but the conclusion false.

For 2, a counterexample is: You have a small, slimy, un-mighty snail, as well as a small, un-slimy, un-mighty, toad.

As far as your attempts of the proofs go ...

**'Proof' 1**

As GrahamKemp already pointed out, you make a big mistake when doing the v Elim in line 7 of the proof attempt for 1: you can *not* infer:

```
 6: big(c) ∨ toad(c)                                         
 7: big(c)                 ∨-elim 6
```

If you go back to the counterexample I provided: if all you have is a small, slimy, and un-mighty toad, then 6 is true (since the only thing that exists, c, is a toad), but 7 is false (since this thing c is not big). As another example:  it is true that every natural number is either even or odd (so we have (Odd(n) v Even(n)),  but obviously we can't conclude Odd(n) by itself from that!

GrahamKemp also said that your line 4 is incorrect, but actually that was just fine. You use the same proof system that I am used to, in which you perform an $\exists$ Elim through the use of a subproof, exactly as you did: so actually you did a good job on the set-up (or 'proof plan' or 'proof skeleton') which is often the most important part of getting these formal proofs done!

**'Proof' 2**

In proof 2, though, you make a mistake in the set-up. Given the premise:

```
 1: ∃x slimy(x) ∧ ∃x toad(x)                   premise
```

you can not set up an existential elimination on both existentials at once. In fact, since this statement is a conjunction, you can't start the process of $\exists$ Elim at all. What you can do is the perform $\land$ Elim to get

```
n: ∃x slimy(x)           ∧ Elim 1

n+1: ∃x toad(x)            ∧ Elim 1
```

And now you can a subproof to eliminate either one, but that will take a subproof for each, rather than one subproof for both at once.